# What am i doing wrong in this code in C++ , Generic Functions?

Tags: c++

I was trying out a sample generic function in C++ , the code follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T max(T a, T b){
    return (a>b)?a:b;
}

int main()
{
    int a=2,b=4;
    float af = 2.01,bf=2.012;
    double ad = 2.11,bd=1.22;
    cout<<max(a,b);
}
```

I am getting the error as

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:20:18: error: call of overloaded ‘max(int&, int&)’ is ambiguous
     cout<<max(a,b);
                  ^
main.cpp:20:18: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:9:3: note: T max(T, T) [with T = int]
 T max(T a, T b){
   ^main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:20:18: error: call of overloaded ‘max(int&, int&)’ is ambiguous
     cout<<max(a,b);
                  ^
main.cpp:20:18: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:9:3: note: T max(T, T) [with T = int]
 T max(T a, T b){
   ^main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:20:18: error: call of overloaded ‘max(int&, int&)’ is ambiguous
     cout<<max(a,b);
                  ^
main.cpp:20:18: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:9:3: note: T max(T, T) [with T = int]
 T max(T a, T b){
   ^
```

What am I doing wrong here ?
What is meant by call of overloaded  `max(int&, int&)` is ambiguous  ?
Why am I getting its argument shown as `&` where as there was no such syntax defined by me above ?

Comment: There is already a built-in function called [`max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max). Try a different name.

Comment: And that's *exactly* the reason why `using namespace std;` is discouraged.

Comment: yeah that worked for me  :) , can you explain me where is it defined ?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: note that even if you just `#include <iostream>` there is a possibility that `std::max` is being defined. The standard include `algorithm` is where **for sure** it is defined, but dependencies between standard headers is unspecified. After you include **any** standard header all of the other names could have potentially been included in `std` namespace.

Comment: @Rakete1111: what is not clear is why C++ forces programmers to use `#include` directives for the standard library, wasting precious neurons to remember what include formally defines what names.

Comment: @kennytm, I would instead recommend just going with `std::max`, because the definition of `max` in above code is doing exactly the same thing (sans the flexibility of having overridable comparator).

Comment: try `max<int,int>(a,b)`

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that C++ already has a `std::max` definition.

Pick another name and everything should be fine.

In C++ the `using namespace std` approach is a bad idea as thousands of names will be injected. Just get the habit of typing `std::` in front of standard names.

Remember also that saving time when writing is not really that important, what is important is saving time when **reading** (normally code is written just once but read and understood many times).

`std::` in front of standard names actually speeds up reading and lets understanding on the spot that what is being used is part of the standard library (not everyone knows the whole standard library by heart).

Answer (score 3):

Skypjack and 6502's answers are spot on so I won't go over that here.

It is also worth noting that the standard's version of `max` is not that clever. You can cause it not to compile with code like this:

```
int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  double b = 1;
  auto c = std::max(a, b);
}
```

yields error message:

> 16 : error: no matching function for call to 'max(int&, double&)'

If we wanted to rewrite max, we might imagine that we were improving it by writing it this way:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace notstd {
  template <typename T1, class T2>
  auto max_any(T1 a, T2 b) -> std::common_type_t<T1, T2>
  {
    return (a>b) ? a : b;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  double b = 1;
  auto c = notstd::max_any(a, b);
}
```

But of course there would be some consequences.

Firstly, `max_any` is now forced to take copies and (possibly) perform conversions. For integers and doubles this is almost not worth mentioning.

But if T1 and T2 were two classes of object that had appropriate conversion operators, calling `max_any` on them could potentially be an expensive operation. It might also have material side-effects.

For this reason, `std::max` is defined in terms of arguments of type `T&`. It forces the caller to perform the conversion. It turns out that this is not a limitation of `std::max`. It is a safety feature.

The function does not inject any hidden side-effects into your code.

In order to maintain 'the path of least surprise' in its behaviour, the standard library sometimes requires that its users spell out the surprising behaviour that they want.

#### Example of surprising behaviour

This program will compile perfectly:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

namespace notstd {
  template <typename T1, class T2>
  auto max_any(T1 a, T2 b)
  {
    return (b < a) ? a : b;
  }
}

struct A {
  A() = default;
};

struct B {
  B() = default;
  B (A const&) { std::exit(100); }
};

bool operator<(B const&, A const &) { return true; }

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  auto c = notstd::max_any(a, b);
  std::cout << "Hello, World\n";
}
```

But it will never print "Hello, World".

Someone maintaining this code might be surprised to learn that.

Comment: Few Questions 1. why would it not print "Hello World"  ? 2. what does A()=default ; statement mean??

Comment: @KapilBhandari `A() = default;` declares a default constructor with a default implementation. It's valid as of c++11. To find out why the program does not print "Hello, World", compile it, single-step and see... :)

Answer (score 2):

There exists already a `max` function in the standard template library (namely `std::max`).
Using the `using namespace` directive, you are *importing* the names from the `std::` namespace to the one in which you are using the declaration itself.
You can still use the following line to pick your implementation of `max`:

```
cout  <<  ::max(a,b);
```

Otherwise, as someone already mentioned, you can choose a different name for your function or use directly the one fron the standard template library.